# AssertionError: Inputs must both have the same timezone, pytz.FixedOffset(-240) != America/New_York

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timezone

File1.py opens a csv into "df" and creates a graph. As the share used is NYC the time is -4.

```
   df_y = pd.read_csv("Meta.csv")
   df_y['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_y['Datetime'])
   df_y.set_index('Datetime',inplace=True)
   
   d = df_y.index[0]
   b = df_y.index[-1]
   
   dt_all = pd.date_range(start=d,end=b,freq='30min')
   
   marged_index = dt_all.append(df_y.index)
   timegap = marged_index[~marged_index.duplicated(keep = False)]
   
   fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)
   fig.add_ohlc(x=df_y.index,
                open=df_y['Open'],
                high=df_y['High'],
                low=df_y['Low'],
                close=df_y['Close'],
                name='stock',
                decreasing_line_color='#21201f',
                increasing_line_color='#21201f',
                row=1, col=1)
   fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False,
                    zeroline=False,
                    showticklabels=True,
                    showspikes=True,
                    spikemode='across',
                    spikesnap='cursor',
                    showline=False,
                    rangebreaks=[
                        dict(values=timegap, dvalue=1800000), # 30min:1000msec*60sec*30min
                    ],
                    rangeslider_visible=False)
   fig.show()
```

The script is working fine but there is a second file cron.py that executes the file1.py in Windows-OS every 30min.

```
    from datetime import datetime
    from time import sleep
    import os
    def main():
        first = True
        t_var=(1,31)
        
        while first is True:
            now = datetime.now()
            if now.minute in t_var:
                os.system("python3 file1.py")
            sleep(80)
```

My PC is in EU and while testing the cron.py below error was showed.
After that file1.py wasn't running not even alone.
My understanding is that there is a conflict with the time zone used. But this is happening on two scripts that run in different time zones.

Unfortunately I am not familiar with python local variable, could you suggest any documentation that explain in detail how it works? Local_vars are not explained in python course books I read. I had other issues with local setup in the past, and I would like to learn the "python architecture" but not sure how to approach

After restarting the PC, both scripts are working fine (reinforces my assumption of local_var)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 2422, in _infer_tz_from_endpoints
    inferred_tz = timezones.infer_tzinfo(start, end)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timezones.pyx", line 328, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones.infer_tzinfo
AssertionError: Inputs must both have the same timezone, pytz.FixedOffset(-240) != America/New_York

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "file1.py", line 59, in graph
    dt_all = pd.date_range(start=d,end=b,freq='30min')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 1105, in date_range
    **kwargs,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 419, in _generate_range
    tz = _infer_tz_from_endpoints(start, end, tz)
    ) from err
TypeError: Start and end cannot both be tz-aware with different timezones
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: When calling `pd.date_range`, both start and end must have the same time zone (or UTC offset, or none). That's what the error is telling you. It seems `df_y['Datetime']` contains mixed time zones. You'll have to clean that up first, before generating the date_range. If you need more help, please add an example of the content of `df_y['Datetime']`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I see what you mean. Any reason why works/fail randomly?
it failed only when I run the cron.py and after restarting the pc was fine again. Does my assumption make any sense?
In [4]: dt_all[-1]
Out[4]: Timestamp('2023-08-17 16:00:00-0400', tz='America/New_York', freq='30T')
In [6]: df_y.index[-1]
Out[6]: Timestamp('2023-08-17 16:00:00-0400', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(-240)')

Comment: I can only give some general tips here, since I don't know the details of your environment. To avoid issues with Python's datetime, you can try to use UTC consistently. E.g. when parsing datetimes in pandas, you can use utc=True; `df_y['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_y['Datetime'], utc=True)` in your example.

Comment: found the source of the issue when download from yfinance timestamp is Timestamp('2023-06-20 09:30:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')  but after the df is saved as csv file and loaded again

df_y = pd.read_csv("Meta.csv")
   df_y['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_y['Datetime'])
   df_y.set_index('Datetime',inplace=True)

Is set as Timestamp('2023-06-09 13:30:00-0400', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(-240)')

so I converted to df_y1.index = df_y1.index.tz_convert('America/New_York')

is there a way of  converting when pd.to_datetime(df[))?
pd.to_datetime(df['date'].tz_convert()) didn't work

Comment: did you try using UTC ? In many cases, that is a safe option, since you can convert both a datetime + UTC offset *and* a datetime + time zone unambiguously to it.